# Looping through all checked checkboxes on page and pulling id into array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE

I have now solved it, changing this line:

```
   idList.push(this.id);
```

to:

```
 $(this).attr('id')
```

I am trying to loop through all of the checkboxes on my page and add the ID's of all that are checked to an array. I have it looping through each checkbox, and detecting whether or not it is checked, but I am having trouble adding the ID of each checked checkbox to an array.

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Javascript:

```
if (element == 'deleteButton' || element == 'allowButton')
            {
                //For testing.
                    //alert("Button Clicked");
                //Create an empty array, so it can be re-sized at run time.
                var idList = [];
                //Loop through all checkboxes, adding each ones id to an array. 
                $('#reported_rages').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
                   //this is the current checkbox   
                    //For testing.
                        //alert("Checked");

                    //Add the current ID to the array
                    idList.push(this.id);
                });

                //return false; // or do something else.
            }
            alert(idList);
```

Comment: Are you actually using pure javascript or JQuery? JQuery will accept pure Javascript because the library is built around it, but without the JQuery library reference you wont get far with the syntax.

Comment: Yes I have the jquery library reference at the top of my page.

Comment: fyi you can answer your own question

Answer (score 1):

Here try implementing these ideas.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/1xvzq26p/)

```js
/*sets variable to global so it can be accessed outside of function*/
var idList = [];
function run(){
    /*clears the original variable*/
    idList = [];
    $('#data').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        idList.push(this.id);
    });
    /*prints after list is populated*/
    console.log(idList);
    $('#results').html(idList);
}
/*binds run function to click of submit*/
$('#submit').click(run);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='data'>
    <input id='1' type='checkbox' />
    <input id='2' type='checkbox' />
    <input id='3' type='checkbox' />
    <input id='4' type='checkbox' />
    <input id='5' type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div id='results'></div>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
```